# How do I conditionally add an attribute to HTML

Tags: astrojs

I'm building a menu with Astro. Some of the items have sub-menus. I have a component that creates my list items. The start of it looks like this. In my example here, I want to conditionally add the `aria-expanded` attribute when `hasSubmenu` (declared in my frontmatter) is true. The following leads to a compile error.

```
<li 
    class="listItem" 
    data-menu-item-id=`${data.label}` 
    role="none" 
    aria-haspopup=`${ariaPopUpValue}`
    {hasSubmenu && "aria-expanded='false'"}
  >
   <a href="#">Menu Item</a>
</li>
```

Adding it similarly to the `aria-haspopup` attribute is incorrect as it will add the `aria-expanded` attribute even when there is no sub-menu. In the case where there is no sub-menu, `aria-haspopup` will be `false` which is the same as it being absent from my HTML. `aria-expanded` is different - it is not valid where there isn't a sub-menu.

How can I conditionally add this (or any) attribute to an HTML element in an Astro component?

Answer (score 2):

You can achieve this doing something like:

```js
// In the frontmatter
const ariaProperties = {
    "data-menu-item-id": data.label,
    "aria-haspopup": ariaPopUpValue,
    ...(hasSubmenu && { "aria-expanded": "false" })
}

// In the html
<li { ...ariaProperties } class="listItem" role="none">
  <a href="#">Menu Item</a>
</li>
```

Comment: Really sad about this. Really it should not be that difficult.

Comment: [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77693665/4200446) shows a better way of adding attributes.