# How conditionally add an HTML attribute to an element in Astro

Tags: html, astrojs, conditional-rendering

I am using Astro and TypeScript.

How do I add conditionally an HTML attribute `rel="noreferrer"` to an element in Astro?

So when `targetBlank = false` it doesn't render `rel` attribute in the dom?

Or is the only solution to conditionally show another HTML element?

```
---
type Props = {
  to: string;
  targetBlank?: boolean;
};

const { to, targetBlank = false } = Astro.props;
---

<a
  href={to}
  target={targetBlank === true ? '_blank' : '_self'}
  rel={targetBlank === true ? 'noreferrer' : ''}
>
  <slot />
</a>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use `undefined`:

```
---
type Props = {
  to: string;
  targetBlank?: boolean;
};

const { to, targetBlank = false } = Astro.props;
---

<a
  href={to}
  target={targetBlank === true ? '_blank' : '_self'}
  rel={targetBlank === true ? 'noreferrer' : undefined}
>
  <slot />
</a>
```